# How to output all array elements after a certain element?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
```

It has 8 value , i want to output all value after the fifth value which is `5`.

so I want to output:

```
6 7 8
```

This is my code:

```
<?php
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);

$i = 0;
while ($i < count($arr)) {
   $a = $arr[$i];
   echo $a ."\n";
   $i++;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array_slice or starting your loops from the desired index:

```
<?php
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);

$i = 5;
while ($i < count($arr)) {
   $a = $arr[$i];
   echo $a ."\n";
   $i++;
}

?>
```

Comment: What explaination you need, about arrays or loops?

Comment: The question is quite vague for a quick reply. To remain simple: You have an array that holds N elements. To walk across the array, you need to loop. This is because the script need to evaluate an information at time. The while you posted works that way. $i=0; is an init counter. When you enter the while the loops will be repeated each time until ($i < count($arr). As you can see $i++ is incrementing the index of $i at each cycle. So if $i=5, the first teration will be 5, then 6,7,8 and then when $i reach 8 will skip since 8!<8. This loops can be anyway problematic using count and not values

Answer (score 2):

Use array_slice()

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);

$output = array_slice($arr, 0, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
$arr = array_slice($arr,5);
$i = 0;
while ($i < count($arr)) {
   $a = $arr[$i];
   echo $a ."\n";
   $i++;
}

?>
```

Comment: array slice is used to slice the array , i have sliced first 5 value from the array .
$arr = array_slice($arr,5);

Comment: read more explanation here http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_slice.asp if my answer solve your problem please accept :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);

    $i = 5;
    while ($i < count($arr)) {
        $a = $arr[$i];
        echo $a ."\n";
        $i++;
    }

?>
```

Comment: you are just starting from index 5 by assigning $i=5.

Answer (score -2):

Simply use [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) along with [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function like as

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
echo implode("\n",array_slice($arr,5));
```

If  you were testing it within browser you simply replace `\n` along with `<br/>`

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/LI7BO)