# How to output value outside a loop?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code.

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);

for($i=5; $i< count($arr); $i++) {

    echo $arr[$i]. "<br>";

}
```

and it outputs:

> 6
> 7
> 8
> 9

I search how to output outside a loop, and I change my code to

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);

$res = "";
for($i=5; $i< count($arr); $i++) {

    $res .= $arr[$i];

}
echo $res. "<br>";
```

but the output is

> 6789

the 4 element become 1. I want to get the output outside the loop and the output will not like be `6789`

I want the output to be

> 6
> 7
> 8
> 9

because I want to use the data like as

> http://1.1.1.0:8000/con/search.json?id=**6** 
> http://1.1.1.0:8000/con/search.json?id=**7**
> http://1.1.1.0:8000/con/search.json?id=**8**
> http://1.1.1.0:8000/con/search.json?id=**9**

and not like as

> http://1.1.1.0:8000/con/search.json?id=**6789**

Comment: `$res .= $arr[$i]."<br>";`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to output all array elements after a certain element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34015475/how-to-output-all-array-elements-after-a-certain-element)

Comment: Its duplicate and if you didn't get the answer over there which is not possible then check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34015475/how-to-output-all-array-elements-after-a-certain-element/34016601#34016601)

Comment: i think . i didn't explain myself clearly.

Answer (score 2):

Best solution(**No Need of for loop, just use implode()**)

```
<?php
    $arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
    echo implode("<br>",$arr);
?>
```

To get values in some range use like this(as suggested my @kojiro)

```
<?php
    $arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
    echo implode('<br>', range(6, 9));
?>
```

Or try like this

```
$res .= "http://1.1.1.0:8000/con/search.json?id=".$arr[$i] ."<br>";
```

Output will be

> 6
>
> 7
>
> 8
>
> 9

Demo [here](https://eval.in/478733)

**EDIT**

```
for($i=5; $i< count($arr); $i++) {
    $res[] = "http://1.1.1.0:8000/con/search.json?id=".$arr[$i];
}
 echo implode("<br>",$res);
```

Comment: `echo implode('<br>', range(6, 9));`

Comment: @kojiro i just added that to my answer.

Comment: Not quite; you didn't use the `range` function and you included the entire sequence instead of just 6..9.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_slice` along with `implode` like as

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
echo "http://1.1.1.0:8000/con/search.json?id=".implode("\nhttp://1.1.1.0:8000/con/search.json?id=",array_slice($arr,5));
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/qZPhW)

Answer (score 0):

use `\r\n`

change this

```
$res .= $arr[$i];
```

to this

```
$res .= "\r\n".$arr[$i];
```

or try this code :-

```
for($i=5; $i< count($arr); $i++) {

$res .= "\r\n".$arr[$i];

}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/478736)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to what you already have:

```
<?php
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
$res = '';
$res2 = '';

for($i=5; $i< count($arr); $i++) {
  $res .= $arr[$i] . "\n";
  $res2 .= $arr[$i] . '<br>';
}
echo $res;
echo $res2;
?>
```

$res on command line will output 6, 7, 8 and 9 in their respective lines. If you are using a browser, $res2 will show 6, 7, 8 and 9 in their respective lines.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will work as per your requirement

```
<?php
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
$res = "";
for($i=5; $i< count($arr); $i++) {
   $res .= $arr[$i] . '<br />';
}
echo $res;
?>
```